# How to use powershell to wait for an action to complete

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I have a script to start VMs/Stop them at a specific time. The issue is, I want the script to only exit when all the VMs are started/running or when they are deallocated/stopped. My current problem is when a VM is starting, it waits until it has started before moving to the next one.

eg: vm1 is starting..
    vm2 is starting..
    vm3 is starting..

```
vm1 is now running..
vm2 is still starting
vm3 is still starting

vm1 is now running..
vm2 is now running..
vm3 is now running..
```

Then script exits.

## Full script here

$ACTION="start"

```
Write-Output "Number of Virtual Machines: $($GetVMS.Name.Count)" `n
$GetVMS | Format-Table

$startstopvm = {

$ResourceGroupName = $args[0]
$Name =  $args[1]
$ACTION = $args[2]

# Get VM status
try {
    $VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -Name $Name -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Status -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
} catch {
    Write-Output ("Cloud not get vm $Name in $ResourceGroupName")
    $Error[0]
    Exit 1 
}

if ($ACTION -eq "start")
{
    foreach ($VM in $VMs)
    {
        if ($VM.Statuses[1].Code -eq "PowerState/running")
        {
            Write-Output ($VM.Name + " in " + $VM.ResourceGroupName + " is already running")
        }
        else
        {
            # The VM needs to be started
            Write-Output ("Starting VM " + $VM.Name)
            $startVM += Start-AzureRmVM -Name $VM.Name -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -AsJob -ErrorAction Continue

            $startTime = Get-Date

            $timeElapsed = $((Get-Date) - $startTime).TotalMinutes

            while ($timeElapsed -lt 2) 
            {
                $startVM = Get-AzureRmVM -Name $VM.Name -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Status -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

                if ($startVM.Statuses[1].Code -match "PowerState/(running|starting)")
                {
                    # The VM started, so send notice
                    Write-Output ($VM.Name + " in " + $VM.ResourceGroupName + " has been started`n")
                    break
                }
                Start-Sleep -s 30
            }

            if ($getStat.Statuses[1].Code -ne "PowerState/(running|starting)")
            {
                # The VM failed to start, so send notice
                Write-Output ($VM.Name + " failed to start`n")  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I am reading the VM name & RG from a file

```
try {
    $VMList = Get-Content C:\Users\local\Desktop\VMs.csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
} catch {
    Write-Output ("Cannot open file...")
    exit -1
}

$Result = @()

foreach ($vm in $VMList) {
    Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $vm.ResourceGroupName, $vm.Name, $ACTION -Verbose -ScriptBlock $startstopvm
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I have done this in the past is to use the `-Wait` parameter on a `Start-Process` cmdlet.

You should be able to implement this with small changes.

Saving your current code block into a seperate `.ps1` i.e. `startstopvm.ps1`

You could then change the `Invoke-Commmand` line to read something like:
`Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $vm.ResourceGroupName, $vm.Name, $ACTION -Verbose -ScriptBlock {Start-Process powershell.exe -Argument "C:\Scripts\Backup.ps1 TestBackup" -Wait}`

Definitely some other ways to do it but an approach like this has always worked for me